# Merge 3 variable into 1

Tags: sas, radix

i have table as below. i want to combine these 3 variable in one. if EX1 has value, the rest is null.

```
id  ex1  ex2  ex3
2   12
3        13
4        13
5             14
```

i need this table

```
id  final
2     12
3     13
4     13
5     14
```

Comment: Look into the `coalesce` function. It will return the first non-missing value.

Answer (score 1):

The [`coalesce`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002518172.htm) function returns the first non-missing argument from a list of arguments.  So for example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  final=coalesce(of x1-x3);
run;
```

Returns the first nonmissing value from x1, x2, x3.

[`coalescec`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002518268.htm) is the character version of the function (it returns a character value).

Another option would be to `sum` the values, so

```
data want;
  set have;
  final = sum(of x1-x3);
run;
```

or in character, `cats` (or `catx` with delimiter) will concatenate them.  These will behave differently than `coalesce`/`coalescec` if more than one value is present, and `sum` will behave differently if 0 values are present,  but will behave identically if exactly one value is always present.